# PHP check if {login.php} if find include file where that appears

Tags: php, include, replace

Hi I am trying to find a way that if I write {} and put a file name in between those simples it will fetch the file from the server and include it where that {} is.

```
$search = "[login]this is a test[members]";
$fetching = preg_replace('#\[([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z])\]#', '', $search);
$fetch->getcontents($fetching);


function getcontents($matches) {
    //print $matches;

    $remove = array("[","]");
    $fetchfile = str_replace("[", "", $matches);
    $this->matches = str_replace("]", "", $fetchfile);
    $url = $this->matches;  

        $file = file_get_contents("modules/$url.php", FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);
        print $file;
    }
```

Comment: do you want the contents of a remote file or local file to be included there and did you want to replace the {} or just have the data between them?

Comment: the file will be on the same server under a folder, I would like it to remove the {} as well and place the file contents in there.

Comment: How about `include 'path/to/file.php'`? How hard is this for you?

Comment: that wont work, due to this is being saved in a MySQL database (Shef)

Comment: be aware of all the security implications this has

Comment: I am not storing PHP code in the MySQL, thats why I want to use {login.php} for example as this is not PHP code

Comment: seems to me that you're trying to create your own template language. You might want to check http://www.twig-project.org/ =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest would be to user regex functions;

```
function get_contents($matches) {
    //return file_get_contents($matches[1]);
    return '::[file='. $matches[1] . ']::';
}

$search_string = 'I\'d like to replace stuff, ie. {login.php} and {logout.php}';

$replaced = preg_replace_callback('#\{([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z]+)\}#', 'get_contents', $search_string);

echo $replaced;
```

note; regex not tested, but will probably work out of the box. Check http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

--- edit, tested the function, works now!

Comment: so the 'get_contents' do i need to use that? or something? I am thinking should it not be $replaced = preg_replace_callback('#\{([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-z])\}#', '$1', $search_string); $this->get_content($replace);

Comment: btw; you should offcourse add some tests in the get_contents function to check if file exists, is readable etc. And if users can add the replacement string check if the file is allowed to be included!

Comment: @Russel: no, check the php manual. But if you would like to have the php code executed you should do something like return include($matches[0]); in the get_contents() function

Comment: ok, I have to also remove { and the } as this does not happen in this script, I have placed it in the function as I think this would be the best practice

Comment: Seems I cant get this to work, when I have two that i need to fetch like [login] and [online] it just wont loop

Comment: you mean the first will be replaced, but not the second? it should replace all occurences by default (see php.net manual for the function)...

Comment: no they seem to join. I'll place the new code I have up above

Comment: check out the updated code, i've tested it and it does indeed replace each string, you should be able to fairly easy rewrite it to include stuff...